# Will cryolipolysis reduce fat cell's total number in human?

Tags: surgery, body-fat, cosmetics

As we known, [fat cell's number will not decrease for adults](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature06902). Without other surgery, new fat cell will replace the dead fat cell and keep the total number constant.

A and B are two people with same height and weight. However A is a people with more fat cell number, B is a people with less fat cell number. Even though A and B shred to same body fat radio, A's fat cell will be more shrinked, i.e. A will be more possible to get fat than B.

My question:

[Cryolipolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_removal_procedures#Cryolipolysis) is a FDA-proved procedure to cause dearth of fat cell. Will Cryolipolysis finally reduce the fat cell's number for adult?